# Sic Community on old, unanswered questions by deleted users

Tags: feature-request, questions, deleted-accounts

Currently, [zero-scored, answerless questions are automatically deleted from all sites after a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/1228) by the Community user.

However, I think this should be expanded to include questions with a zero or positive score by users who do not exist.

(insert image of such a question here, with a freehand red circle drawn around the user)

Face it.  Old users are going to know that the asker is gone, and if they answer the question, there will be no possibility that their answer will be selected as correct, and less chance their answer will get upvoted.  New users might actually spend time answering the question, thus wasting their efforts.

Yes, an answer may help someone searching for the same problem.  However, if that searcher does not find, and asks a new question, they will get their answer and the user providing the help will get the rep they would have been denied.

<sub><sub>Also we'll see the end of these damned "can XYZ select the correct answer on questions where the user has been deleted?" feature requests here on Meta.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 5):

If the question has a positive score it means that the site feels that it's net value is positive.  Questions don't exist for the sole purpose of giving rep to people through accepted answers.  Since the score is positive it's saying that even without additional answers, the question alone was in some way valuable content to the community.

Comment: The question is useless without an answer.  Again, older users won't answer it and if a new user does they end up screwed out of rep.  If someone *does* have the same question, they can create a new question.  Therefore your answer is invalid, and you should eat worms, hair is a bird, etc.

Comment: I would add to this by saying that there are many more points in upvotes for a good answer than there are in a check mark.

Comment: *"they end up screwed out of rep"*...a whole 15 points. If it's a good answer, the community will pay far more.

Comment: `The question is useless without an answer.` I disagree.  Sometimes you can learn more from reading a good question than an answer to it.  There are plenty of times where, in the process of searching for an answer, I find a question asking something more complex that answers my simple question in the process of painkilling the more complex question (and thus I can ignore the answers).  Next, for anyone not hitting the rep cap already, and as has been said already, you're going to get more rep from upvotes than acceptance of an answer.

Comment: @Servy: That's a stretch.  I'd like to see some examples of excellent questions by deleted users.

Comment: @Won't You're the one proposing the feature.  The burden is on you to prove that all old *upvoted* unanswered questions by deleted users are bad, not on me to prove that they aren't.

Comment: @Servy: Oh, sorry, my bad.  I guess you can make any claim you want, then.  Would still like to see this mythical question that is so brilliant that it answers your question by its very existence.  However, it wouldn't hurt if I had some stats on these black-hole questions.  If I have some spare time this weekend I will update.

Comment: @Won't's burden is not to prove that "_all_ old upvoted unanswered questions by deleted users are" **bad**, but that they are _not worth keeping_, that the site would be better off without them. He has indeed given an argument for that.